# Stripe Webhook timed out

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks, request-timed-out

Stripe has informed me that it's not receiving a response from my Webhook URL.

A Webhook test returns:

> "Test Webhook Error: Timed out."

I understand this to mean that a connection could not be established to the Webhook URL. However, I can't figure out why.

The script loads fine if I execute it manually from the browser.

According to my web host (GoDaddy Managed WordPress), there aren't any IPs being blocked. I also had them check that cURL was enabled, and to up my `max_execution_time` and a few other `.ini` settings... to no avail.

Any other ideas what might be causing this "timed out" error from Stripe?

Comment: Is your webhook endpoint able to accept POST requests?

Comment: Did you check the `access log` to verify Stripe is posting anything?

Comment: Yes, if I post to the webhook endpoint, I can output the post data.

Comment: From what I can tell, there is no data being posted by Stripe to the webhook URL. After about 30 seconds, the webhook test returns the "timed out" error.

Comment: if you load it manually from the browser that would indicate that code is expecting a GET request not a POST request. Stripe will send a JSON body in the POST request, so if you believe its not, then there is an issue in how you're determining it is not. The timeout would be because your server is not responding within the 30 second timeout Stripe has.

Comment: Even if I have the script simply echo "test" I still get a "timed out" error. Wouldn't this indicate that it's not the script at webhook URL that is the issue?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I use Google Cloud Run so I suspect the problem is that a cold start takes too long...

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue.  We are pretty sure this is related to Godaddy's managed Wordpress.  They are building a new data center and we have noticed that some of the newer installs are having issues with InfiniteWP.  InfiniteWP is a program that lets you login to various Wordpress sites all from the same dashboard, it works fine on all the Godaddy managed WP sites except the ones in the new data center.  The problem it has with these new installs is a timeout error, similar to the timeout error from the Stripe Webhook.

So at this point we don't need Stripe webhooks to work to accept payments, so our hope is that Godaddy will eventually fix this problem. Im really not sure that is the problem but its our best guess.

HWD, was this a Wordpress install you setup in the past 60 days or so? That might help to confirm the issue.

Comment: Yeah, this error started occurring when we moved to the Managed WordPress recently.